# reserved keyword is used in protobuf in Python

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

In general, I have a protobuf definition which used a Python keyword "from". It works in Java/C#/C++, but when comes to Python, I could not assign value to it.

Here is the detail of my problem.

I have a protobuf definition like below:

```
message Foo
{
    required int64 from = 10
    ...
}
```

Since the field "from" is a keyword in Python, after I generated the python code, I could not compile the code as below:

```
foo = Foo()
foo.from = 1234
```

Then, I tried to use setattr() to set the attribute:

```
setattr(foo, 'from', 1234)
```

That gives me a Protobuf exception:

```
AttributeError: Assignment not allowed to composite field "from" in protocol message object.
```

I could not change the definition at this moment because it has been used widely in the system. Any help would be appreciated if I can workaround to use the "from" attribute in Python.

Below is the ProtoBuf generated code:

```
import sys


_FOO = _descriptor.Descriptor(
  name='Foo',
  full_name='com.kerneljoy.Foo',
  filename=None,
  file=DESCRIPTOR,
  containing_type=None,
  fields=[
    _descriptor.FieldDescriptor(
      name='from', full_name='com.kerneljoy.Foo.from', index=0,
      number=10, type=3, cpp_type=2, label=2,
      has_default_value=False, default_value=0,
      message_type=None, enum_type=None, containing_type=None,
      is_extension=False, extension_scope=None,
      options=None),
  ],
  extensions=[
  ],
  nested_types=[],
  enum_types=[
  ],
  options=None,
  is_extendable=False,
  extension_ranges=[],
  oneofs=[
  ],
  serialized_start=28,
  serialized_end=47,
)

DESCRIPTOR.message_types_by_name['Foo'] = _FOO

Foo = _reflection.GeneratedProtocolMessageType('Foo', (_message.Message,), dict(
  DESCRIPTOR = _FOO,
  __module__ = 'Foo_pb2'
  # @@protoc_insertion_point(class_scope:com.kerneljoy.Foo)
  ))
_sym_db.RegisterMessage(Foo)
```

Comment: I've never used protocol buffers before, but a common idiom in Python is to affix an underscore to a reserved word if you want to use it as an identifier. Perhaps the Python implementation does the same thing? `foo = Foo(); foo.from_ = 1234`.

Comment: Interesting question. Could you please post the resulting Python code that is generated by protobuf? Or from some minimal working example, if you can't post the original.

Comment: @chepner thanks! I tried this as well. but seems that doesn't work. It will report the error that from_ is not defined.

Comment: @Unapiedra cool. I'll attach the code

Comment: attached the ProtoBuf generated python code

Comment: How do you use the generated code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After couple attempts, I found the setattr() and getattr() can workaround this. Because in my production code, the 'from' refers to another protobuff definition. So the solution here is as below:

```
foo = Foo()
object = getattr(foo, 'from')
object.bar = 'value'
object.bar2 = 'value2'
```

Answer (score 0):

It is strange to realize the "HasField" but does not pair "GetField". Please, consider yet another implementation:

```
def msg_GetField(msg, name, default_value=None, raise_on_not_exist=True):
    result = default_value
    #
    exist = False
    items = msg.ListFields()
    for desc, value in items:
        if name == desc.name:
            result = value
            exist = True
    #
    if raise_on_not_exist:
        if not exist:
            raise ValueError('No property')
    #
    return result
```

You can use it as utility method or make mixin if you know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

If "from" was a primitive variable (not composite) . the set attribute will work (you can see in the error msg : "AttributeError: Assignment not allowed to **composite field**" )- but then if Foo is included in other object you will need to use "MergeFrom" to insert Foo to insert it into the including object.

example:

pb:

```
message Foo
{
   required int64 from = 1
} 
message Bar
{
  required Foo foo = 1
}
```

the following code should work:

```
foo=Foo()
bar=Bar()
setattr(foo, 'from', 1204)
bar.MergeFrom(foo)
```

Answer (score 0):

For **composite field** like Bar.*from*

```
# proto

message Foo {
  string f1 = 3;
  string f2 = 4;
}
message Bar {
  string b1 = 1;
  Foo from = 2;
}
```

You can convert `Bar` to `dict`, set a **from** value and convert `dict` back to `Bar`:

```
from google.protobuf.json_format import MessageToDict, ParseDict

bar = Bar(b1='some_string')
foo = Foo(f1='f1', f2='f2')

bar_dict = MessageToDict(bar)
foo_dict = MessageToDict(foo)
bar_dict['from'] = foo_dict

bar_with_foo = ParseDict(bar_dict, bar, ignore_unknown_fields=True)
```